# Julia: is there a common style for functions on Vectors and colum-wise Matricies?

Tags: matrix, vector, julia

For example, a function that calculates mean and standard deviation for each column vector.

For Vector:

```
function meanstd(x::Vector)
    len = length(x)
    m = 0
    m2 = 0
    for i = 1:len
        m += x[i]
        m2 += x[i]*x[i]
    end
    s = sqrt.((m2 - m.*m./len)./(len-1))
    m /= len
    m, s
end
```

For Matrix:

```
function meanstd(x::Matrix)
    len, d2 = size(x)
    m = zeros(d2)
    m2 = zeros(d2)
    for j=1:d2
        for i = 1:len
            m[j] += x[i,j]
            m2[j] += x[i,j]*x[i,j]
        end
    end
    s = zeros(d2)
    for j = 1:d2
        s[j] = sqrt.((m2[j] - m[j].*m[j]./len)./(len-1))
        m[j] /= len
    end
    m, s
end
```

How can I write the only one fast function with common syntax for both types?

**UPD:**

`trailingsize` function (`import Base.trailingsize`) gives the size of next dimensions for arrays, even if this dimension does not exist.

`ndims(v)` function gives the total number of dimensions.

This particular function can be generalized for vectors and columns of matricies as follows (But its output type is always array, event if it is one number):

```
function meanstd(x::Array{T}) where T<:Real
    len = size(x,1)
    d2 = ndims(x) == 1 ? 1 : size(x,2);
    s = zeros(1, d2)
    m = zeros(1, d2)
    m2 = zeros(1, d2)
    for j=1:d2
        for i = 1:len
            m[j] += x[i,j]
            m2[j] += x[i,j]*x[i,j]
        end
    end
    for j = 1:d2
        s[j] = sqrt.((m2[j] - m[j].*m[j]./len)./(len-1))
        m[j] /= len
    end
    m, s
end
```

Comment: I'm no expert at this, but I suspect the answer lies [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/statistics.jl) on line 75. (it's the implementation of `mean` in `Base` for abstract arrays and a region of the array over which to perform the operation - if I had more time I'd try to puzzle it out as I'm interested myself!)

Comment: @Sairus Not quite sure what you mean, but what about `maplast(f, x) = squeeze(mapslices(f, x, 1), 1)`?

Comment: If the question is about *style*, I think the convention is to have an Array argument followed by a scalar dimension or a list of dimensions on which to operate, returning a structure with size corresponding to at least the remaining dimensions (see `mapslices` from the previous comment).

Comment: A language-agnostic comment, I would recommend to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance concerning numerical stability before trying to implement something.